# How to include all dns records and IP address of a server in automatic certificate enrollment of Microsoft AD CS?

Tags: dns, active-directory, certificate

In my company there are a lot of servers which users remotely login to them to do their duties. We have enabled computer certificate auto enrollment for them to assure secure connection. But because we have some servers with multiple DNS records, it is probable that users don't use the main DNS name of the server or use the IP Address of it so they get certificate error when they are trying to connect. 
Therefore we want a way to include all the DNS records and the IP address of the server in the Subject Alternate Name of the certificate automatically.